# How to use java.util.logging in Weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, java.util.logging

I have an application that was migrated from Glassfish to Weblogic, and it uses java.util.logging as logging framework.

The only way I have found to make the logs work is by editing the logging.properties file of the JVM and restart the server. This solution is awkward and gives problems because the log is written to a different file than the standard ones for weblogic, so we have to look at too many files for a log in a clustered environment. Besides, for some reason this does not work on some Windows systems.

Is there a way to keep using standard java logging to write messages to weblogic's standard log files? I tried the instructions on [this page](http://disaak.blogspot.com/2009/11/migrating-to-weblogic-use.html) but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 5):

WebLogic Server ships with a JDK logging handler which will pick up log messages emitted from JDK logging framework and direct them into the WebLogic Server logging system.

Set the default logging level for new ServerLoggingHandler instances in logging.properties as well as adding the ServerLoggingHandler to the handlers.

```
handlers = weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler
weblogic.logging.ServerLoggingHandler.level = ALL
```

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13739/logging_services.htm#CHDBBEIJ

To direct the JDK logging framework to use the logging.properties file, the standard System property java.util.logging.config.file is used. With WebLogic Server, this can be easily accomplished by setting the JAVA_OPTIONS System property with the corresponding value.

$ export JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/Users/xxx/Projects/Domains/wls1035/logging.properties"

Some more hints here: http://buttso.blogspot.de/2011/06/using-slf4j-with-weblogic-server.html